# What do the $i,j$ stand for when writing $A=(a_{ij})$?

Tags: matrices, notation

We often write matrices as $A=(a_{ij})$. But what do the subscripts mean? Does it simply say that $A$ is a $2$-dimensional array?

I read somewhere in the definition of the transpose of a matrix that if $A=(a_{ij})$ then its transpose is $A^T=(a_{ji})$. I had a problem with this. 
By $(a_{ij})$ it is understood that we are talking about the matrix 
$\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&...&a_{1n}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&...&a_{2n}\\...&...&...&...\\...&...&...&...\\a_{m1}&a_{m2}&...&a_{mn}\end{bmatrix}$.

Then $(a_{ji}),(a_{mn}),(a_{pq})$ should all stand for the same matrix (the one above).

Could someone explain to me the meaning of the notation or provide a better one?

Comment: $i,j$ are the indices themselves; writing $A=(a_{ij})$ just tells you what the variables you will use for the entries and indices are. It doesn't tell you how big the matrix is. $A^T=(a_{ji})$ is a shorthand for $(A^T)_{ij}=A_{ji}$.

Comment: @Ian Oh sorry I messed up while writing the question. I edited it. Sorry!

Comment: @Ian So does $A_{ij}$ stand for the $(i,j)$th entry of $A$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @Ian Could you elaborate on your first comment? What roles do $i$ and $j$ play in $(a_{ij})$? And how is $(a_{ij})$ any different from $(a_{mn})$?

Comment: A subtle aspect might be the difference of *declaring* a matrix as opposed to *referring* to a matrix after it's been declared.  Saying "$(a_{i,j})$ is a matrix" is to call it into existence.  We could just as easily said "$(b_{p,q})$ is a matrix" or "$(c_{j,i})$ is a matrix".  Saying "$(a_{j,i})$ is the transpose" is to *refer* to a matrix and assuming that the original matrix $(a_{i,j})$ already exists.  And this is the matrix where each term $a_{i,j}$ from the $i$th row $j$th column is placed in the $j$th row and the $i$th column.

Answer (score 1):

The first subscript, usually $i$, stands for the row index. The second one stands for the column index.

The point when writing $A^T=(a_{ji})$ is that $i$ and $j$ are not *really* dummy variables here as you seem to imply: what is meant is really

> $$A^T=(b_{ij})\qquad \text{where}\ \  b_{ij}=a_{ji}\ \ \text{for all
>  $i$ and $j$.}$$

$a_{ji}$ is the entry at the intersection of the $j$-th row and the $i$-th column of $A$ (you know that because here $j$ comes first), and it is meant to become the entry at the intersection of the $i$-th row and the $j$-th column in $A^T$ (you know that because in $b_{ij}$, $i$ comes first).

Comment: So whenever we write a matrix as $(a_{ij})$ we mean that $i$ runs over $1,2,3,...m$ ($m$=number of rows) and $j$ runs over $1,2,3,...,n$ ($n$=number of columns). And the matrix is the one that I mentioned in my question? That is, $a_{ij}$ is the element sitting at the intersection of row $i$ and column $j$? And so $(a_{ji}),(a_{pq})$ on their own refer to the same matrix?

Comment: @HritRoy Exactly. Without context, $(a_{ji})$ and $(a_{pq})$ would refer to the same matrix since there would be no way to guess that $i,j,p,q$ are not supposed to be dummy variables.

Comment: Then $A^T=(a_{ji})$, strictly speaking, is just a shorthand for what you've given in the box above? What you gave is very logical and seems consistent with the idea of the notation used.

Answer (score 1):

The row and the column,  respectively.

In other words,  $a_{ij}$ is the entry on the $i$-th row and $j$- th column of the matrix.

For instance,  for the identity matrix $a_{ij}=\delta _i^j=\begin {cases} 0, i\not =j\\1, i=j\end {cases}$.

For the transpose you interchange $i$ and $j$, thus swapping rows and columns.

Comment: If $(a_{ij})$ means that the entry on the $i$th row $j$th column is $a_{ij}$ then $(a_{ji})$ should mean that the entry on the $j$th row $i$th column is $a_{ji}$ which is the same matrix!

Comment: $a_{i,j} \ne a_{j,i}$  If $(a_{i,j}) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2&3\\4&5&6 \end{bmatrix}$ then $(a_{j,i}) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4\\ 2&5\\3& 6 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: The main thing is $(a_{i,j})$ is informal and incorrect.  It is understood to be. $\begin{bmatrix} a_{1,1}&a_{1,2}&a_{1,3}\\a_{2,1}&a_{2,2}&a_{3,3}\end{bmatrix}$ where the $i$ row is $a_{i,1}$ to $a_{i,m}$ and $(a_{j,i})$ is understood to be $\begin{bmatrix} a_{1,1}&a_{2,1}\\a_{1,2}&a_{2,2}\\a_{1,3}&a_{3,1}\end{bmatrix}$ where the $i$ row is $a_{1,i}$ to $a_{n, i}$.

Answer (score 0):

When you refer to $a_{i,j}$ it is presumed you have a table of values.  $a_{5,2}$ is the value that is the second item of the fifth row.  $a_{7,9}$ is the nineth value of the seventh row.

When you wrote $(a_{i,j})$ in this *informal* notation it means the array of placing the terms in their proper row and columns.

So $(a_{j,i})$ assumes the *same* values but this is the arrow were the  columns are rows are transposed.  That is $a_{5,2}$ was the value of the second item of the fifth row of the original matrix.  It is now placed in the fifth item of the second row.

Now you might be saying (I'd be saying) Wait a minute! When were those terms ever defined in the first place?  And what can I say... this is one of the reason the notation is informal.

What we should say is something like "Let $A$ be a matrix whose terms are $a_{i,j}$ for the indexes $i,j$ where the row $i$ runs from $1$ to $m$ and the column index $j$ runs from $1$ to $n$" or something like that.

Then once it's been *declared* we can then refer to $(a_{j,i})$ as the transposed matrix.

In that context *after* we have declared the matrix $(a_{i,j})$ to exists, refering to a matrix  $(a_{m,n})$ or $(a_{p,q})$ wouldn't really make any clear sense.  We have no idea just how the index variables $m,n$ or $p,q$ are supposed to relate.

*BUT* if we did the *before* we had defined the matrix and we declared $(a_{m,n})$ that'd just be the same as declaring $(a_{i,j})$; it's just that from here on out we'll be using the index variable *labels* (they are labels; nothing more) $m,n$ instead.

tl;dr

When we *declare* a matrix we can use the notation $(a_{i,j})$ to be any matrix with $i$ being the index variable for the row and $j$ being the index variable for the column.  The is *no* significance to the variables or positions $i$ and $j$ and we could use any other variables in any order.

But one we *have* declared the matrix, all the terms $a_{i,j} $ are now fixed and any *future* reference to them will refer to that specific value $(a_{j,i})$ will *not* refer to the transpose as the row index $i$ is in the column positive and the column index $i$ will be in the row position.

Comment: Your last paragraph confused me a little..

Comment: When you declare $(a_i,j)$ is a matrix you are declaring: $i$ is the variable we use for the rows and $j$ is the variable we use for the columns.  Now that you've declared it, any reference to any $a_{*,*}$ or to $i, j$ will be understood.  So $(a_{j,i})$ will be the matrix where the $m$th row and then $n$th column will be the term $a_{n,m}$.